# Firebase admin and user account

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am building an Android app with firebase. Simple users would sign in and add data to the database. Users would be able to see only their own data. Then I need to have a single Admin account that sees all data in the firebase database. How should I go about it?

Answer (score 4):

Did you secure your database in any way yet? If not, I recommend getting started with the [documentation for Firebase security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/).

I typically secure my database as [shown in the section on securing user data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/user-security#section-structuring-db) and then have a list of UIDs in the database for users with special permissions.

So with a JSON structure like this:

```
users
  Power3000Uid: { ... }
  PufUid: { ... }
admins
  Power3000Uid: true
```

And security rules like this:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "auth.uid == $uid || root.child('admins').child(auth.uid).exists()"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In words the `.read` rules is: "you can read this data if you're the owner of it, or if you're an admin". In the sample above this means that you can read anyone's data, but I can only read my own.

Depending on your exact needs, you'll need to repeat the admin-clause in various places in the database, or (what I usually do) just have it once at a high level in your JSON tree.

Comment: Thank you. One more thing. My app would have 3 sign in options - facebook, google and email. FB and Google would normally use simple user and email would be used by an admin. So I manually have to create an account and then put it under the admin node?

Comment: If you take my simple approach, you will have to somehow add the UID of those users to the `/admins` node. There are many other ways to implement this, but mostly they'll vary in how you populate this so-called whitelist. They'll likely end with a similar look up in the rules: "if the user exists in /place, they have special powers".